# Como faço para receber uma variável ou função dentro do input do TextFormField sem a necessidade de digitar e salvar na lista com o Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

**Preciso inserir um texto dentro do input para não haver necessidade de digitação, foi uma forma de editar os dados armazenado no Firebase, quando efetuo a edição dos dados, vai para uma tela de edição com os dados em cada input, para o usuário editar ou não, conforme achar necessidade.
Não estou conseguindo fazer isso, sempre me obriga a digitar algum caractere, tentei funções, variáveis, várias formas e nenhuma obtive êxito. Se alguém puder dar uma ideia diferente ou uma solução, fico agradecido.**

**Declarei um controle para o nome, dessa forma:**

`TextEditingController _controleNome = new TextEditingController();`

**Além de inseri-la no initState:**

```
void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _controleNome.text = 'Teste';
}
```

```
                              Container(
                                width: 330,
                                height: 50,
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                  autofocus: true,
                                  cursorColor: Colors.brown,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, height: 1.5, color: Colors.brown),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  controller: _controleNome,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Nome',
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.brown, fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                    isDense: true,
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                  ),
                                  onChanged: (text){
                                    editado = true;
                                    setState(() {
                                      _editaContato.nome = text;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
```

Comment: Tente `initialValue: 'valor inicial'`

Comment: Foi a primeira alternativa que usei, mas preciso do controlador, fora que também não funciona. Tanto o initialValue, como um controller, não aceitam o texto inicial sem acrescentar algo, obriga a escrever mais algum caractere, só assim ele salva na lista e no banco.

Answer (score -1):

Utilize o TextEditingController com o parâmetro "text" inicial.

```
 final controller =  TextEditingController(text: "Teste") ;
```

Caso o valor nao for constante, não seria possível iniciar o valor.

```
class TextFieldWidget extends StatelessWidget {
final String text;
  TextFieldWidget({this.text = "test"});

final controller =  TextEditingController(text: text) ; // aqui o text vai apresentar um erro por ser uma variável e não um valor constante.
```

Nesse cenário você precisará utlizar o initState para inicializar o controller.

```
class TextFieldWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      final String text;
      TextFieldWidget ({this.text = "teste"});
    
    
      @override
      State<TextFieldWidget > createState() => _TextFieldWidgetState();
    }
    
    class _TextFieldWidgetState extends State<TextFieldWidget> {
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        controller =  TextEditingController(text: widget.text) ;
        super.initState();
      }
      late final controller;
```

OBS: Existem outras formas de fazer isso utilizando gerenciamento de estados, streams por exemplo. Nesse outro cenário você teria um streamBuilder e quando fosse adicionado um valor inicial, o TextFormField seria reconstruído com esse novo valor sem precisar trabalhar com o initState.